# Getting both numpy.partition and numpy.argpartition outputs efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using python 3.6 and numpy. I have a n dimensional array. I need to perform both partition and argpartition on the last dimension of the array. I can obviously call both functions, but it feels like wasting resources. Is there a way to get the results of both np.partition and np.argpartition at the same time? There should be a way to get the result of np.partition applying to the array the indices I get from np.argpartition but I don't see it at the moment!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get those `argpartition` indices and then use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to get the partitioned array.

Thus, an implementation for a generic ndarray of any number of dimensions and along any generic axis, would be like so -

```
def partition_results(a, k, axis=-1):
    idx = np.argpartition(a, k, axis=axis)
    index_arr = list(np.ix_(*[range(i) for i in a.shape]))
    index_arr[axis] =  idx
    return idx, a[index_arr]
```

[`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) gives us the "spread-out" range arrays to accomplish the task of `advanced-indexing`. These range arrays are needed to cover all dimensions corresponding to the lengths of the axes in `argpartition` indices array except the last one, for which we have those `argpartition` indices themselves. This setup is needed for such an indexing operation.

So, with the approach of using two separate calls to `np.argpartition` and `np.partition`, we would have it, like so -

```
def partition_results_exclusive_way(a, k):
    idx = np.argpartition(a, k, axis=-1)
    part_arr = np.partition(a, k, axis=-1)
    return idx , part_arr
```

We will use it for comparison on performance and value verification in the next section.

Sample run and runtime test -

```
In [496]: a = np.random.rand(20,20,20,20,20)

In [502]: A0, B0 = partition_results_exclusive_way(a, 10)

In [503]: A1, B1 = partition_results(a, 10)

In [504]: np.allclose(A0,A1)
Out[504]: True

In [505]: np.allclose(B0,B1)
Out[505]: True

In [506]: %timeit partition_results_exclusive_way(a, 10)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.6 ms per loop

In [507]: %timeit partition_results(a, 10)
10 loops, best of 3: 76 ms per loop
```

Dissecting a bit more on the performance numbers, let's time `argpartition` and `partition` separately -

```
In [509]: %timeit np.argpartition(a, 10, axis=-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.6 ms per loop

In [510]: %timeit np.partition(a, 10, axis=-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.6 ms per loop
```

So, the `advanced-indexing` operation costed us around half of  what we had with `np.partition`. We are definitely saving there!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It raises an error on 3 dimensional array though, with IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together

Comment: @Ant Are you working with 3D arrays only, or looking for a generic ndarray (of generic number of dims) solution?

Comment: I am looking for a generic ndarray; I don't expect the dimension to go above 4 or 5 but it can definitely be bigger than 3 :)

Comment: @Ant Check out the edits for a generic ndarray solution.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much :D So if I understand correctly you basically take all rows/columns in the first n-1 dimensions, and then the correct indices for the n-th dimension; which is what I wanted :D Only thing, could you clarify the call to np.ix_?

Comment: @Ant Added few comments on it.